# развертывание приложения React на GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

Мучался долго, но у меня получилось залить реакт приложение на github pages. Работает с одним но: когда мы переходим по ссылке, которую гитхаб нам дал для пользования, переход происходит как бы не на главную страницу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И хорошо, что кнопка home есть, можно перейти на главную. НО тут еще одно но: перейдя по ссылка на главную, адресс меняется с https://dozzadore.github.io/patternsPage/   на https://dozzadore.github.io/ и все бы ничего, только вот если эту ссылку использовать, то на экране ошибка 404. т.е. я по этой ссылке нахожусь, но если кому-нибудь дам или сам зайду по этому адресу https://dozzadore.github.io/ , то ошибка 404...
Приложу package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-carousel",
  "homepage": "https://dozzadore.github.io/patternsPage",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "jquery-zoom": "^1.7.21",
    "js-image-zoom": "^0.7.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-medium-image-zoom": "^5.1.3",
    "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "sunzi-image-magnifiers": "^1.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

и App.js

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/Header/Header';
import Main from './components/Main/Main';
import Items from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/Items";
import Info from "./components/Main/Pages/Info/Info";
import Patterns from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/Patterns";
import ItemPage01 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page01/ItemPage01";
import ItemPage02 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page02/ItemPage02";
import ItemPage03 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page03/ItemPage03";
import ItemPage04 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page04/ItemPage04";
import ItemPage05 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page05/ItemPage05";
import ItemPage06 from "./components/Main/Pages/Items/itemsPages/page06/ItemPage06";
import PatternPage01 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage01/PatternPage01";
import PatternPage02 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage02/PatternPage02";
import PatternPage03 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage03/PatternPage03";
import PatternPage04 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage04/PatternPage04";
import PatternPage05 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage05/PatternPage05";
import PatternPage06 from "./components/Main/Pages/Patterns/PatternsPages/PatternPage06/PatternPage06";
import DivManeken from "./components/DivManeken/DivManeken";


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Header />
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} />
            <Route path="/items" element={<Items />} />
            <Route path="/patterns" element={<Patterns />}/>
            <Route path="/info" element={<Info />} />
            <Route path="/items/itempage01" element={<ItemPage01 />}/>
            <Route path="/items/itempage02" element={<ItemPage02 />}/>
            <Route path="/items/itempage03" element={<ItemPage03 />}/>
            <Route path="/items/itempage04" element={<ItemPage04 />}/>
            <Route path="/items/itempage05" element={<ItemPage05 />}/>
            <Route path="/items/itempage06" element={<ItemPage06 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage01" element={<PatternPage01 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage02" element={<PatternPage02 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage03" element={<PatternPage03 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage04" element={<PatternPage04 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage05" element={<PatternPage05 />}/>
            <Route path="/patterns/patternpage06" element={<PatternPage06 />}/>
        </Routes>
        <DivManeken />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Ссылка на репозиторий https://github.com/dozzadore/patternsPage

Comment: Попробуйте в `package.json` у значения`"homepage": "https://dozzadore.github.io/patternsPage"` добавить в конце слеш.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson я пробовал, все так же. Смысл в том, что на обычный хостинг я заливал и все работало как надо, а на гит хаб Пейдж вот такие траблы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

мне помогло поменять главный путь '/' на '/название репозитория'

```
<Route exact path="/" element={<Main />} /> <<<-Было
```

```
<Route exact path="/patternsPage" element={<Main />} /> <<<-Стало
```

Answer (score 0):

В Browser router добавь атрибут с значением названия твоего репозитория например

`<BrowserRouter basename='назвние_твоего_репозитория_на_github'> <App/> </BrowserRouter>`